# Could not find group:ros.rosjava_zeroconf

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Trying out the new apps](http://www.ros.org/wiki/android_core#Trying_out_the_new_apps) in `android_core` tutorial fails with following message. Does anyone have a clue?

```
$ ./gradlew debug --stacktrace
:android_app_chooser:deployLibs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':android_app_chooser:compile'.
> Could not find group:ros.rosjava_zeroconf, module:rosjava_zeroconf, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
  Required by:
      ros.osrf_rosandroid:android_app_chooser:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':android_app_chooser:compile'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
        :
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:456)
    ... 71 more
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 2.643 secs
```

["The old way"](http://www.ros.org/wiki/android_core#The_old_way) runs just fine:

```
$ roscd osrf_rosandroid
$ make conf
$ make
```

Ubuntu 12.10, hg SHA `cc26f896f2f93a39d73a5eec4e8d8c4139e7fbc0`
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59092/could-not-find-group:ros.rosjava_zeroconf/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is because `rosjava_zeroconf` is not compiled.
Input the following commands.

> > $ roscd rosjava_zeroconf

> > $ ./gradlew install

Then try it again.

---

Originally posted by [KazutoMurase](https://answers.ros.org/users/2505/kazutomurase/) with karma: 116 on 2013-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1